# Attempting to merge XML when a duplicate key is detected

Tags: xslt

The following is my input record. Each LoadNumber can repeat multiple times if there is more than one stop.  I would like to convert the following:

```
  <Load>
     <LoadData>
        <ShipmentNumber>24609038</ShipmentNumber>
        <TrackingType>FK </TrackingType>
        <LoadNumber>90621234</LoadNumber>
        <StopSequence>1</StopSequence>
        <CarrierNumber>22104</CarrierNumber>
        <SCAC>WOLH</SCAC>
        <ShippingName>Somewhere DC                             </ShippingName>
        <ShippingAddress>115 S MAIN ST                     </ShippingAddress>
        <ShippingCity>CLEVELAND                 </ShippingCity>
        <ShippingState>OH </ShippingState>
        <ShippingZip>54915       </ShippingZip>
        <ShippingCountry>US </ShippingCountry>
        <PromisedDate>116321</PromisedDate>
        <PromisedTime>153000</PromisedTime>
        <DestinationName>COMPANY1           </DestinationName>
        <DestinationAddress>4000 3RD AVE N                    </DestinationAddress>
        <DestinationCity>MINNEAPOLIS           </DestinationCity>
        <DestinationState>MN</DestinationState>
        <DestinationZip>55443     </DestinationZip>
        <DestinationCountry>US</DestinationCountry>
        <ShippingDate>116320</ShippingDate>
        <ShippingTime>230000</ShippingTime>
    </LoadData>
        <LoadData>
        <ShipmentNumber>24615865</ShipmentNumber>
        <TrackingType>FK </TrackingType>
        <LoadNumber>90621234</LoadNumber>
        <StopSequence>2</StopSequence>
        <CarrierNumber>22104</CarrierNumber>
        <SCAC>WOLH</SCAC>
        <ShippingName>Somewhere DC                             </ShippingName>
        <ShippingAddress>115 S MAIN ST                     </ShippingAddress>
        <ShippingCity>CLEVELAND                 </ShippingCity>
        <ShippingState>OH </ShippingState>
        <ShippingZip>54912       </ShippingZip>
        <ShippingCountry>US </ShippingCountry>
        <PromisedDate>116321</PromisedDate>
        <PromisedTime>133000</PromisedTime>
        <DestinationName>COMPANY 2             </DestinationName>
        <DestinationAddress>3 KENT ST                       </DestinationAddress>
        <DestinationCity>SHOREVIEW               </DestinationCity>
        <DestinationState>MN</DestinationState>
        <DestinationZip>55126     </DestinationZip>
        <DestinationCountry>US</DestinationCountry>
        <ShippingDate>116320</ShippingDate>
        <ShippingTime>230000</ShippingTime>
    </LoadData>
    <LoadData>
        <ShipmentNumber>24469114</ShipmentNumber>
        <TrackingType>FK </TrackingType>
        <LoadNumber>11325877</LoadNumber>
        <StopSequence>1</StopSequence>
        <CarrierNumber>22104</CarrierNumber>
        <SCAC>WOLH</SCAC>
        <ShippingName>Somewhere DC                             </ShippingName>
        <ShippingAddress>115 S MAIN ST                     </ShippingAddress>
        <ShippingCity>CLEVELAND                 </ShippingCity>
        <ShippingState>OH </ShippingState>
        <ShippingZip>54915       </ShippingZip>
        <ShippingCountry>US </ShippingCountry>
        <PromisedDate>116318</PromisedDate>
        <PromisedTime>235900</PromisedTime>
        <DestinationName>Test DC                         </DestinationName>
        <DestinationAddress>450 DECLARATION DR                 </DestinationAddress>
        <DestinationCity>MCDONOUGH               </DestinationCity>
        <DestinationState>GA</DestinationState>
        <DestinationZip>30253     </DestinationZip>
        <DestinationCountry>US</DestinationCountry>
        <ShippingDate>116316</ShippingDate>
        <ShippingTime>130000</ShippingTime>
    </LoadData>
</Load>
```

Into this:

```
  <Loads>
   <Load>
       <Action>add</Action>
      <BillOfLading<90621234</BillOfLading>
      <Carrier>
         <SCAC>WOLH</SCAC>
      </Carrier>
      <PickUpStops>
         <PickUpStop>
            <ActionPickup>add</ActionPickup>
            <NamePickup>Somewhere DC</NamePickup>
            <StopIdPickup>0</StopIdPickup>
            <StopSequencePickup>0</StopSequencePickup>
            <StreetAddressPickup>115 S MAIN ST</StreetAddressPickup>
            <CityPickup>CLEVELAND</CityPickup>
            <StatePickup>OH</StatePickup>
            <PostalPickup>54915</PostalPickup>
            <CountryPickup>US</CountryPickup>
            <EarliestPlannedPickupTime>2016-11-15T23:00:00Z</EarliestPlannedPickupTime>
            <LatestPlannedPickupTime>2016-11-15T23:00:00Z</LatestPlannedPickupTime>
         </PickupStop>
      </PickUpStops>
      <DeliveryStops>
         <DeliveryStop>
            <ActionDelivery>add</ActionDelivery>
            <NameDelivery>COMPANY1</NameDelivery>
            <StopIdDelivery>1</StopIdDelivery>
            <StopSequenceDelivery>1</StopSequenceDelivery>
             <StreetAddressDelivery>4000 #RD AVE N</StreetAddressDelivery>
             <CityDelivery>MINNEAPOLIS</CityDelivery>
            <StateDelivery<MN</StateDelivery>
            <PostalDelivery>55443</PostalDelivery>
            <CountryDelivery>US</CountryDelivery>
            <EarliestAppointmentTime>2016-11-16T15:30:00Z</EarliestAppointmentTime>
            <LatestAppointmentTime>2016-11-16T15:30:00Z</LatestAppointmentTime>
         </DeliveryStop>
         <DeliveryStop>
            <ActionDelivery>add</ActionDelivery>
            <NameDelivery>COMPANY 2</NameDelivery>
            <StopIdDelivery>2</StopIdDelivery>
            <StopSequenceDelivery>2</StopSequenceDelivery>
            <StreetAddressDelivery>3 KENT ST</StreetAddressDelivery>
            <CityDelivery>SHOREVIEW</CityDelivery>
            <StateDelivery<MN</StateDelivery>
            <PostalDelivery>55126</PostalDelivery>
            <CountryDelivery>US</CountryDelivery>
            <EarliestAppointmentTime>2016-11-16T13:30:00Z</EarliestAppointmentTime>
             <LatestAppointmentTime>2016-11-16T13:30:00Z</LatestAppointmentTime>
         </DeliveryStop>
      </DeliveryStops>
    </Load>
   <Load>
      <Action>add</Action>
      <BillOfLading<11325877</BillOfLading>
      <Carrier>
         <SCAC>WOLH</SCAC>
      </Carrier>
      <PickUpStops>
         <PickUpStop>
            <ActionPickup>add</ActionPickup>
            <NamePickup>Somewhere DC</NamePickup>
            <StopIdPickup>0</StopIdPickup>
            <StopSequencePickup>0</StopSequencePickup>
            <StreetAddressPickup>115 S MAIN ST</StreetAddressPickup>
            <CityPickup>CLEVELAND</CityPickup>
            <StatePickup>OH</StatePickup>
            <PostalPickup>54915</PostalPickup>
            <CountryPickup>US</CountryPickup>
            <EarliestPlannedPickupTime>2016-11-11T13:00:00Z</EarliestPlannedPickupTime>
            <LatestPlannedPickupTime>2016-11-11T13:00:00Z</LatestPlannedPickupTime>
         </PickupStop>
      </PickUpStops>
      <DeliveryStops>
         <DeliveryStop>
            <ActionDelivery>add</ActionDelivery>
            <NameDelivery>Test DC</NameDelivery>
            <StopIdDelivery>1</StopIdDelivery>
            <StopSequenceDelivery>1</StopSequenceDelivery>
            <StreetAddressDelivery>450 DECLARATION DR</StreetAddressDelivery>
            <CityDelivery>MCDONOUGH</CityDelivery>
            <StateDelivery<GA</StateDelivery>
            <PostalDelivery>30253</PostalDelivery>
            <CountryDelivery>US</CountryDelivery>
            <EarliestAppointmentTime>2016-11-13T23:59:00Z</EarliestAppointmentTime>
            <LatestAppointmentTime>2016-11-13T23:59:00Z</LatestAppointmentTime>
     </DeliveryStop>
     </DeliveryStops>
   </Load>
</Loads>`
```

I must also find a way to convert the julian date in my input into my desired output format as well.  The XSLT below is as far as I've gotten.  I've attempted to use the LoadNumber as a key, but I am unsure how to merge two input records together using this key into a single load with two stops, so the xslt is incomplete.  Can anyone give me some advice?  Thanks.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

      <xsl:key name="load" match="LoadData" use="LoadNumber"/>

      <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="LoadData[generate-id(.) = 
                       generate-id(key('load', LoadNumber))]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="LoadData">
         <Loads>
        <Action>
           <xsl:text>add</xsl:text>
            <BillOfLading>
               <xsl:value-of select = "LoadNumber"/>
            </BillOfLading>
            <Carrier>
               <SCAC>
               <xsl:value-of select = "SCAC"/>
               </SCAC>
             <PickUpStops>
               <PickUpStop>
                  <ActionPickup>
                     <xsl:text>add</xsl:text>
                  <ActionPickup>
                  <NamePickup>
                     <xsl:value-of select = "ShippingName"/>
                  </NamePickup>
                  <StopIdPickup>
                     <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                  </StopIdPickup>
                  <StopSequencePickup>
                     <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                  </StopSequencePickup>
                  <StreetAddressPickup>
                     <xsl:value-of select = "ShippingAddress"/>
                  </StreetAddressPickup>
                  <CityPickup>
                     <xsl:value-of select = "ShippingCity"/>
                  </CityPickup>
                   <StatePickup>
                     <xsl:value-of select = "ShippingState"/>
                  </StatePickup>
                  <PostalPickup>
                     <xsl:value-of select = "ShippingZip"/>
                  </PostalPickup>
                  <CountryPickup>
                      <xsl:value-of select = "ShippingCountry"/>
                  </CountryPickup>
                   <EarliestPlannedPickupTime>
                     <xsl:value-of select = "concat(ShippingDate,'T',ShippingTime)"/>
                  </EarliestPlannedPickupTime>
                  <LatestPlannedPickupTime>
                     <xsl:value-of select = "concat(ShippingDate,'T',ShippingTime)"/>
                  </LatestPlannedPickupTime>
                </PickupStop>
             </PickupStops>
             <DeliveryStop>
                <ActionDelivery>
                   <xsl:text>add</xsl:text>
                </ActionDelivery>
                <NameDelivery>
                   <xsl:value-of select = "ShippingName"/>
                </NameDelivery>
                 <StopIdDelivery>
                   <xsl:value-of select="key('load',LoadNumber)//Stop
                </StopIdDelivery>
         </Loads>   
      </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "*I must also find a way to convert the julian date in my input into my desired output format as well.*" Ask a separate question about that. BTW, those dates look Gregorian to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am unsure how to merge two input records together using this key
>   into a single load with two stops

You need to re-use the same key in order to get the records in the current group. Here's an example, reduced for clarity to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the principle:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="load" match="LoadData" use="LoadNumber"/>

<xsl:template match="/Load">
    <Loads>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="LoadData[generate-id() = generate-id(key('load', LoadNumber)[1])]" mode="pickup"/>
     </Loads>   
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LoadData" mode="pickup">
    <Load>
        <!-- more here -->
        <PickupStops>
            <PickupStop>
                <!-- more here -->
                <CityPickup>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ShippingCity"/>
                </CityPickup>
                <!-- more here -->
            </PickupStop>
        </PickupStops>
        <DeliveryStops>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('load', LoadNumber)"/>
        </DeliveryStops>
    </Load>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LoadData">
    <DeliveryStop>
        <!-- more here -->
        <CityPickup>
         <xsl:value-of select="DestinationCity"/>
        </CityPickup>
        <!-- more here -->
    </DeliveryStop>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Loads>
  <Load>
    <PickupStops>
      <PickupStop>
        <CityPickup>CLEVELAND                 </CityPickup>
      </PickupStop>
    </PickupStops>
    <DeliveryStops>
      <DeliveryStop>
        <CityPickup>MINNEAPOLIS           </CityPickup>
      </DeliveryStop>
      <DeliveryStop>
        <CityPickup>SHOREVIEW               </CityPickup>
      </DeliveryStop>
    </DeliveryStops>
  </Load>
  <Load>
    <PickupStops>
      <PickupStop>
        <CityPickup>CLEVELAND                 </CityPickup>
      </PickupStop>
    </PickupStops>
    <DeliveryStops>
      <DeliveryStop>
        <CityPickup>MCDONOUGH               </CityPickup>
      </DeliveryStop>
    </DeliveryStops>
  </Load>
</Loads>
```